# Best way to update UI when the user removes an item in the database in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular7

I would like to know  the best way to update the user interface when the user deletes an item in the  database. I have the following scenario: in  the user interface I have addresses that are bound to an array in the component, this array is assigned based on the data on the database. When the user click the "delete" button I perform an http request to delete the item in the database, but of course, the user interface doesn't update.It would be easy if I could use router.navigate() so that the component refreshes itselft.  But when I navigate to the same route angular doesn't reload/refresh the component. The only solution I can think about is to write some typescript code to remove the item from the array.

My model:

```
 export class Address {

  public id: number; //unique id I can use to remove the item
 ...
  }
```

relevant code of my component.

```
addresses: Array<Address>;

....

 removeAddress(id: number) : void {

//service used to make http requests, I pass the id to delete
this.addressService.removeAddress(id).subscribe((res) => {

     //How can I update the UI on Success?

},    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the item from the array if the response comes with no errors (HTTP 200). This will save traffic for the user. But u also can reload the remain items from the database.

```
delete myArray[key];



const index = myArray.indexOf(key, 0);
if (index > -1) {
   myArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Your answer opened my mind with new possibilities. That's what I wanted!

Comment: I liked the second option better. I just had to reassign the addresses array by recalling the function I use  to populate the addresses on component initialization. I didn't have thought about this option.